# Error after import java-libGDX project

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, libgdx

I just want to send the source code to my friends to continue the work but seem like when I export it (as .zip) it always error somehow.

It's a desktop game that built in Eclipse and I can export it to runable jar, it runs fine.

but I need to send the source code, so if anyone know how to fix it, I'll be grateful. (I think it might be about the gradle thing? have no idea)

Comment: your friend need to build the source first via gradle

Comment: show your error log ?

Comment: Oh yeah! It work now! look like my friend forgot to import it lol